# MDX: What is the val() function in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

MDX: What is the val() function in MDX

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Store Size] AS 
VAL([DimMangedPopulation].[Managed Population Key].CURRENTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("Program Name"))

SELECT
{[Measures].[Store Size]} ON COLUMNS,   
[DimManagedPopulation].[Program Name].&[BHI] ON ROWS
FROM Sales
```

Please see the below image for output

[image]

Comment: It's converting string values (e.g.  "100") to number (e.g. 100)

Comment: @Whytheq, can you please answer this question.

Comment: Madam, with all due respect, this question is already answered. This site is about "why" something won't work or "how" to get something working. You are asking what the val() function does, which I have already answered. Next time, instead of stackoverflow, when you want to know the purpose of a function which Microsoft built, better look up MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Looking back at the image, it seems you used a wrong choice of words:

> "What did the val() function in MDX"

Your question should have been, "Why it returns 0"

Assuming, my deduction is correct, the answer is : `Val()` would return a value of 0 for a character string argument. You can check this with a simple example.

```
with member abc as val("abc")

select abc on 0 
from [AdvWorks]
```

In your case, you selecting the property "Program Name", which seems to be a character string rather than a number, and hence you get a 0.

HTH

Comment: thank you for the suggestion and explanation for the question.